# Pandas excel to python for long column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm very new to python and I'm using Pandas to read an excel file, my file column is having 197 values to it, so when I read them with Pandas, I don't get all of the values " as shown in the picture"

not the full excel sheet is appearing

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
xl =pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sheet1 = xl.parse()
z=str(sheet1)
z=z.replace('212/',"")
z=z.replace('/1',"")
print(z)
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question to show those values? What you see is normal behavior. If you want see specific rows, try loc or iloc.

Comment: Hi Chris, yes I want to see these values, the hidden ones. because when I export them to txt file they don't appear they also appear like dots " ... "

Comment: How are you exporting to txt file? Why not use the df.to_excel? More info on that from here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: I used this to open the file and export the values to it " my_file = open('test.txt','w+') ", but it showed exactly as the picture shows

Comment: what I want is to show the whole numbers without the dots, I'll try to use the df.to_excel and see what happens, Thanks.